# По какой причине шрифты в SVG не загружаются?

Tags: css, svg, шрифты, frontend

SVG изображение имеет текст со специфичным шрифтом, он подключается внутри кода SVG.

```
<defs
     id="defs4514">

        <style type="text/css">
          @font-face {
            font-family: 'Comfortaa';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('Comfortaa Regular'), local('Comfortaa-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/comfortaa/v12/1Ptsg8LJRfWJmhDAuUs4TYFq.woff2) format('woff2');
            unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
          }
        </style>
</defs>
```

Оборачивание декларации font-face в CDATA эффекта не дает

**При размещении на странице** шрифт игнорируется, а **при открытии в браузере** картинки, шрифт **загружается**, почему так?

Comment: https используется везде?

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет, https только в адресе шрифта

Comment: Остальное - http? Попробуй заменить в адресе шрифта `https://` на `//`.

Comment: Не оборачивай style  defs-ОМ

Comment: @Александр Хорошо, вы показали, как подключаете Web fonts в стилях. Добавьте ещё пожалуйста ваш код, как вы добавляете символы шрифта в Html